# How to pass var from controller into a different view with Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, variables, view

I am new to Cakephp and indeed OOP, so forgive me if i haven't fully grasped the MVC concept yet.  I have search a lot but cannot find an answer - perhaps my way of working below is not correct.  I hope you can help.

I am building a site which will have many elements relating to their tables and data.  I intend to use a view to pick and choose the relevant elements and any parameters needed.

For example, the homepage of my site will have two elements - a latestusers element and a latestscores element.  I am trying to use a view not related to either the users or scores models/controllers, stored in 'other/index.ctp'.

I have tried using set() to pass a variable from the users controller (latestusers action) into the other/index.ctp view, but the viewVars remain empty.  Could this be due to scope of the variable (i think it is fine for a view in the users folder, i.e. a view specific to the users controller).

I could achieve what i want to do by using global variables, but i think this is missing the point of MVC/OOP.  Would be grateful for any suggestions.

I can include code if need be - it is fairly basic at this stage - but i feel my problem lies with how i am going about things, not the code itself.

Cheers,
James

Comment: Yes, example code would be a good idea to see what exactly you are doing. I don't think you'd want to mess with viewVars directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue is with the scope. If you're going to use variables in the element you'll need to pass them in from your view. So the flow would look something like this

1. Controller `$this->set()`s the variable into your current view/layout
2. Your view/layout calls `$this->element` with the current element path.
3. Your element uses those variables.

In number 2 you need to pass your variables as an array of data. This section on the cookbook gives more information : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements

```
<?php echo$this->element('helpbox',     
      array("helptext" => "Oh, this text is very helpful."));?>
```

Note - I didn't understand part of the question. Just want to make sure you are passing data to the correct view. You should not be calling the view of another controller in your active controller.

Your `other/index.ctp` should be an element and that element should be called from your layout.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply John.  I thought i must be doing something illegal!  After years of writing procedural code, its taking me a little while to get my head round the MVC, particularly with regards to page flow.  I will rethink what i am trying to achieve.